# Criação de um banco de dados simples com o NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, mysqli, entidade-relacionamento, warnings

Sempre que crio um *DER*(Diagrama Entidade-Relacionamento) em um banco de dados, e em seguida digito esse diagrama no Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento, para digitalizar o diagrama criado e para também realizar a inserção de registros e suas respectivas consultas no banco de dados. Sempre quando eu começo a criar uma tabela, digito os seguintes comandos:

```js
USE db_evento;
CREATE TABLE tb_aluno(
 id_aluno INT(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 cd_rm_aluno INT(5),
 nm_aluno VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 dt_nascimento_aluno DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Quando eu coloco este código para executar no *MySQL*, a primeira linha é executada sem nenhuma exceção, mas na segunda linha, o programa reconhece um erro lógico falando que a tabela `tb_aluno` já existe. Dentro do console aparece um código de erro de *nº 1050*.

[image: Console do MySQL Workbench]

Para resolver este problema, coloquei o `IF NOT EXISTS` junto do `CREATE TABLE` para eliminar o erro 1050 e criar uma tabela já existente no modelo, só que eu digitei o seguinte código e o visor do console retornou estes resultados:

```js
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_aluno( // CRIAR TABELA SE NÃO EXISTIR tb_aluno
 id_aluno INT(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 cd_rm_aluno INT(5),
 nm_aluno VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 dt_nascimento_aluno DATE NOT NULL
);
```

Resultado no trecho de código acima no *MySQL*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Resultado na verificação de todas as tabelas que já criei dentro do *MySQL*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Desta forma, eu fiquei confuso na hora de utilizar este `IF NOT EXISTS` na hora de implementar este operador em todas as tabelas que eu já fiz. Há outra forma de criar tabelas sem que haja este tipo de alerta no console, de tal forma que todas as linhas do código sejam verificadas sem nenhum erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *Error Code 1050* é dado por conta que já existe uma tabela com a mesma nomeclatura da que você está tentando executar em sua *query*.

> Há outra forma de criar tabelas sem que haja este tipo de alerta no
>   console, de tal forma que todas as linhas do código sejam verificadas
>   sem nenhum erro?

O resultado de sua verificação em outras tabelas já criadas no *MySQL* não é considerado erro, e sim, um alerta(*Warning*) que por padrão, o seu [SGBD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados) lhe informa por existir uma tabela já criada. 
A sua query não é executada, pois, assim como mesmo citou, somente **// CRIAR TABELA SE NÃO,EXISTIR**, como já existia, logo nenhum código foi executado.

**Soluções para seu problema**

1. Caso você queira manter os registros que já foram cadastrados em sua tabela, aconselho você utilizar o comando [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) e adicionar as novas modificações em sua tabela existente.
2. Se os dados já cadastrados não forem tão relevante pra você, aconselho você executar [`DROP TABLE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_drop_table.asp)`IF EXISTS 'suatabela' ;` e executar a sua *query* de criação.

Comment: @pe.Math esclarecido?

Comment: simm, desculpe pela demora acabei desistindo de usar o stack overflow. @RXSD

Comment: Tudo bem amigo, seja bem vindo de volta!

Answer (score -1):

Desse modo há algum problema em usar DROP antes de CREATE?

`cd_rm_aluno` usei como uma suposição, não sei qual é a referência de chave que você usa, portanto deve alterar.

```
ALTER TABLE `tb_outra`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sua_restricao` FOREIGN KEY (`cd_rm_aluno`) 
      REFERENCES `tb_aluno` (`cd_rm_aluno`);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_aluno`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_aluno` (
  `id_aluno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nm_aluno` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: eu já tentei utilizar este método, mas só que aparece outro erro: 00:25:18 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_aluno Error Code: 1217. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 0.110 sec - Traduzindo: Não é possível excluir ou atualizar uma linha pai: uma restrição de chave estrangeira falha

Comment: Você deve excluir a linha da tabela onde há referência da chave estrangeira antes de excluir a tabela aluno.

Comment: Depois de corrigir o relacionamento de chave estrangeira, sua instrução de DROP funcionará.